# Bullets not displaying in IE8 when li element has -ms-filter gradient background

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, css

I have an ordered list that has a gradient background for each `<li>` element. For IE8/9 support (I only need to support IE8+ and Chrome), I use an -ms-filter (see code snippet below).  Everything looks great in Chrome, but in IE8, the list numbers don't display.  If I remove the -ms-filter from my CSS, however, everything displays perfectly (except, of course, the gradient isn't there).  Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<ol id="myList">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
#myList li {
    background-color: #def;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#EDF3FF', EndColorStr='#CCEEFF')";
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #EDF3FF 0%, #CCEEFF 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #EDF3FF), color-stop(1, #CCEEFF));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #EDF3FF 0%, #CCEEFF 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #EDF3FF 0%, #CCEEFF 100%);
    padding: 3px 0px;
    width: 130px;
    margin: 3px;
}
```

Any ideas for why this isn't working? Any possible fixes? (besides removing the gradient for IE8)

Comment: When I can get IE8 to render anything at all, I go home and consider my day a success.

Comment: Try using a image fallback for IE8...